# Find all possible x and y points on a curve

Tags: geometry

I have few x and y coordinates, say for example 10, using which I have plotted a curve on graph (green curve shown in image). I have a line intersecting this curve (blue line shown in image).

I am trying to find out all the possible points on the curve (green line shown in image) as well as on the blue line. I am doing this to check for the common point and then mark their intersection.

Is it possible to find all the possible x and y points on the green curve and on the blue line?

See image.[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Can you explain what you mean by "I have a curve on a graph"?  Otherwise, it seems like the object you want and the object you have are exactly the same.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hi @MatthewLeingang. Thank you for your reply and pardon me for the ambiguity in question. I have few x and y coordinates, say for example 10, using which I have plotted a graph. I have a line intersecting this curve. I am trying to find out all the possible points on the curve as well as on the line. I am doing this to check for the common point and then mark their intersection.

Comment: Hi @JoséCarlosSantos, thank you for your reply. I have updated my question, kindly have a look at it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. So you have some points and you're drawing a graph between them? "I have a line intersecting this curve" - what line? Does it have some restrictions? To me it sounds like you're doing some kind of interpolation ...

Comment: Hi @MattiP. I have rephrased my question. Sorry for the using confusing terms. I am trying to implement a certain algorithm in my mobile app.

Comment: also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51873654/1199154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find anyway to get all the points from a curve/line chart.

So in order to find two exact similar points on two line charts, I divided them into multiple line segments and checked for the two intersecting line segments.  I needed this solution for my Android app.

The way I accomplished it is by first dividing both the line charts into multiple line segments.

Then I found out their intersection point using determinant as mentioned [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-point-of-intersection-of-two-lines/).

If given lines be :

```
a1x + b1y = c1
a2x + b2y = c2
```

Then;

```
determinant = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1
  if (determinant == 0) {
     // Lines are parallel
 }
 else {
      x = (c1*b2 - c2*b1) / determinant
      y = (a1*c2 - a2*c1) / determinant

   // (x,y) is the point of intersection of two line segments

  }
  ---------
  Example:
  ---------
  Input : A = (1, 1), B = (4, 4)
          C = (1, 8), D = (2, 4)
  Output : The intersection of the given lines
           AB and CD is: (2.4, 2.4)

  Input : A = (0, 1), B = (0, 4)
          C = (1, 8), D = (1, 4)
  Output : The given lines AB and CD are parallel.
```

Then I checked whether that point of intersection lies on both the line segments:
To check if "x" is between "a" and "b";

```
      int m = (a+b)/2;

      if(Math.abs(x-m) <= (Math.abs(a-m)))
      {
         // The x lies on both the line segments.
      }
```

Comment: Can you give any particular reason for down-voting this?

Comment: Your question was not clear for anyone to understand what you are asking. Subsequently, you answered your own question with a huge chunk of code which I feel is completely lacking in context and explanation. If you could answer your own question without anyone's help at all, why post it on this site?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my answer, hope that you will be more gracious towards me. I am happy to share here how I solved my problem.